# Is WP-Env on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Normally I would declare this off topic, after all XAMPP or WAMP are off topic. But WP Env has been put into the official core repos, and given a very deliberate grey ambiguity by its developers as to it's *officialness*.

A user asked a question here:

[wp-env mysqlcheck error:1130](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/385059/wp-env-mysqlcheck-error1130)

I believe that answering the question will involve zero WordPress knowledge, and some Docker knowledge. Should it be closed as off topic?

Comment: Is [VVV](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/) on topic?

Comment: I don't believe VVV itself is on topic, the meta environment however would. If someone needed help adding a site to VVV I'd direct them to the VVV slack or github. If someone wanted to provision the meta environment to work on a .org site then I'd consider it on topic as it's the code that powers wordpress.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, ticks all the boxes:

- lives in the official WordPress GitHub repo and NPM namespace
- is developed and maintained by WP people
- is recommended from make.wordpress.org

The fact that it is not PHP- but Docker- and Node-specific doesn't make it less WordPress. If the OP had posted the question on a more Docker oriented site, they might have problems as wp-env seems to do its very own stuff (similar to Local).

So niche knowledge that exceeds general Docker knowledge is required.